# Android ExoPlayer , Play/Pause button in the middle of VideoPlayer

Tags: android, mediacontroller, exoplayer

Im using Exoplayer for playing the videos in my Android App. I want to place the play/pause button in the middle of the video player view(Like the one in the image below). How to achieve this
[image]

Im just inflating a new layout in place of Android default mediaController. Im wondering is it the correct way to get the below kind of image layout

media_controller.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="#CC000000"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="4dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/pause"
        style="@android:style/MediaButton.Play"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="play/pause" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/time_current"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="4dip"
        android:paddingLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="4dip" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/mediacontroller_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="32dip" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/time"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="4dip"
        android:paddingRight="4dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="4dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried creating buttons and adding them to your layout?

Comment: I have tried it , but the buttons are coming at the bottom

Comment: can you post your layout and show me where exactly did you try adding those buttons?

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: And the `ImageButton` is the button you were trying to add?

Comment: Yeah , basically thats the play/pause button

Comment: Then that's what you're gonna get. You're trying to put it in the horizontal LinearLayout inside the one that already stores the seekbar and video time information. That's why it appeared at the bottom. What is your knowledge of different layouts in android? Can you post your entire layout?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124647/discussion-between-sasank-sunkavalli-and-bartek-lipinski).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved in **Exoplayer 2.1.0** . The Exoplayer library has a way to define our own custom layouts for Media Controller playbacks, It is called as **PlayBackControllerView**. It can be achieved by overriding layout files. To customize these layouts, an application can define layout files with the same names in its own res/layout* directories. These layout files override the ones provided by the ExoPlayer library. We can achieve this by creating **exo_playback_control_view.xml** file in the application’s res/layout directory.

**exo_playback_control_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="bottom"
   android:layoutDirection="ltr"
   android:background="#22000000">

   <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/play_pause_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:paddingTop="4dp"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:gravity="center">

       <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play"
          style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"/>

       <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_pause"
          style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"/>

   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

      <TextView android:id="@id/exo_position"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="14sp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:paddingLeft="4dp"
          android:paddingRight="4dp"
          android:includeFontPadding="false"
          android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>

      <SeekBar android:id="@id/exo_progress"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_height="32dp"
          android:focusable="false"
          style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>

      <TextView android:id="@id/exo_duration"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="14sp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:paddingLeft="4dp"
          android:paddingRight="4dp"
          android:includeFontPadding="false"
          android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>

  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Ref : [Customizing Exoplayer's UI components](https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/customizing-exoplayers-ui-components-728cf55ee07a#.e71unbbak)

Comment: How to add click event in our Activity for these customize buttons ?

Comment: @GyanSwaroopAwasthi Using the custom view id, You can use findViewById() method in your Activity/Fragment class. Then you can just set view.setOnClickListener to listen for the click events.